# Ubuntu Core snap writable location

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-core, 16.04

I am new to snappy. For learning purposes I'm trying to make an apache2 snap. 
Created the snap with snapcraft and installed it on Ubuntu core. The problem I am facing is that Apache is trying to write the log files and it is complaining they're read-only.

As I understood, ubuntu-core should be read-only file system and the snaps should be writeable. Or should I point the log files in Apache to `/writable/tmp` ?

I am using ubunfstu core 16.04 and created snaps in Ubuntu server 16.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would propose that you set your logs in `$SNAP_DATA` for now. Note that we will have soon some unversion DATA path available for your snaps, so that those data aren't copied for each upgrade/rollback.
Then, you can ship something in your snap like logrotate to handle log rotations and removal at your own convenience.

However, your use-case is quite interesting and not something that was discussed about AFAIK (logs best practices), do you mind raising this on the snappy-devel ML to trigger the discussion? (see https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/support/)